# What is the point of "svn update"

Tags: svn

I just found recently that `the working copy is not automatically update after a commit`. For example, the remote repository shows that the `Revision` and `Last Changed Rev` are `63`, but the working copy shows that they are `62`.

I don't know why SVN is designed as this. On the internet, people say that it is good to update the working copy before you commit, although it is not always necessary. But why not always being update by default?

`svn update` also can "update" to an earlier revision. For me this is used to do some test only, I won't commit after doing some changes on an earlier revision obtained from `svn update`. If I really want to `revert to an earlier revision`, there is `revert` option when I use TortoiseSVN (But I don't know if this uses `svn update`).

So I don't know the point of `svn update`, i.e

- Why not update automatically after a commit?
- What is the point of `svn update to an earlier revision`?

Comment: If you shipped a product to customers, then did enhancements, then got a customer bug Report, you probably want to go back to the old Version that shipped to customers to debug it. Then you might use svn update with an earlier Version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `svn update` to update your working copy to the latest revision on the server.

Think about that you might not even have write permissions to a repository, you're just checking out a copy of it. Then you might want to update it later on to get the latest changes other developers made to the repository.

`update` is generally used to update your working copy. By default it updates to the latest revision on the server, but you could just as well update to a specific revision. You might want to do this if the latest revision introduces an issue. Then you might want to check out an earlier revision that might not have the issue.

Comment: I totally forget the situation you mentioned! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, `revert` just reverts your **local** changes. Basically it will put your working copy to the state of the last update you made. To update to another revision than the one you have as a working copy, you need the `update` command.

A reason why the update is not done automatically before or after the commit could be that you maybe don't want to be bothered getting the updates of the whole repository.

Another one could be: you were working on a file, and colleague has already commited a dirty fix, and you don't want your changes to be merged with his: you want only your version to be there.

And sometimes it actually is mandatory to perform an update before a commit since you cannot commit something that would conflict with the latest revision on the server: in this case, typically your client will ask you to update first.

But in any case, I think that it's just that conceptually those are two different things: you update to get the last state and you commit to push your changes. It's usually a good practice to update just before a commit, but it shouldn't be necessary either.